# Wagtail KeyError 4 at /admin/

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm getting this error after creating a new model on a new app recently installed.
This is not the first time I'm getting this error and I haven't been able to identify the problem.

```
   Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['home',
 'search',
 'flex',
 'streams',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail.core',
 'modelcluster',
 'taggit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\urls\__init__.py", line 109, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\auth.py", line 188, in decorated_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\home.py", line 116, in home
    RecentEditsPanel(request),
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\home.py", line 98, in __init__
    pages = Page.objects.specific().in_bulk(page_keys)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 698, in in_bulk
    return {getattr(obj, field_name): obj for obj in qs}
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wagtail\core\query.py", line 403, in specific_iterator
    yield pages_by_type[content_type][pk]

Exception Type: KeyError at /admin/
Exception Value: 4
```

I'm able to access the admin interface through the edit button of my main page but instead of seeing all the child pages of the Home Page, I'm getting a 'Servor Error' on the side bar.

Anyone knows what caused this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Okay so I'm going to explain what I did. I tried to change the models name. Wagtail didn't seem to like that. I'm new to programming so I didn't know that it was going to mess up my database. I started a new project and avoided changing models name. so far, so good.